# Stateless vs Stateful ViewModel

Tags: design-patterns, wpf, mvvm

Here are two links which briefly describe the difference between the two:
[stateless](http://www.xamlpatterns.com/stateless-view-models), [stateful](http://www.xamlpatterns.com/stateful-view-model)

In short in the "Stateless" scenario we bind views directly to models, view models just expose the whole objects, not their properties, so we don't need any synchronization between models and view models.

In the "Stateful" scenario we make a copy of a model object and bind it to a view.

Are there any downsides in the "Stateless" scenario? Because it seems like it's a way to go by default. What stops us from implementing INotifyDataErrorInfo, INPC and all the stuff at the level of models?

Comment: I think this is related and may actually be the question you're trying to ask: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/289822/mvvm-strictness-of-views-referencing-models/289837#289837

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What stops us from implementing INotifyDataErrorInfo, INPC and all the stuff at the level of models?

That how the model is described by the business and how it is shown in the UI can (and will) be different.

While simple scenarios might make it seem that models and UIs are exactly the same, reality is not so simple. ViewModel's primary purpose is to transform the business domain model into form that is easy to bind to UI.

Comment: Can't we rely on converters in order to cover the necessity for transforming model values?

Comment: @EngineerSpock No. Converters are too simple. I'm not talking about simple 1:1 mappings. I'm talking about drastic changes in shape of the model and in exposed behavior.

Comment: Maybe, it would be better in such cases to roll out model wrappers? (though, seems like any benefits of "stateless" VM in this case disappear).

Comment: @EngineerSpock What is difference between "model wrapper" and ViewModel? To me, the ViewModel is the "model wrapper".

Answer (score 1):

Nearly ever user interface is going to require the ViewModel to have state that does not belong in the model so I believe that there is no such thing as a "stateless" ViewModel in MVVM.

Some examples:

- Enabled/Disabled state of user interface controls
- Selected items (listboxes, radio buttons, etc)
- Input data that has not yet been validated or committed to the model

Comment: you can have multiple models, which can store those information. For example I have a settingsModel for the state of the checkboxes in my app. Makes it quite easy to store all the settings in a json or other stuff.